# Formatting with java: Mixing text and pictures

Tags: java, drawing, format

I have a certain text, that i want to annotate for the user. Unfortunately i don't even see where to begin. My algorithm gives as output a range on a string. What i am going for is something like this:

[image: example]

I would need two ways to marker the Characters ( Blue line, red line), maybe also to invert the character (Give a character a different background), or make them fat. What is especially difficult is aligning the Pictures (here designated by two black dots) with the characters. Since the characters should be in Courier New, i could know where to put the offset, but i cannot seem to do it.

Lastly i would have to apply a break after X characters and begin a new line, just like in the picture. I have not found any example how to approach this with java yet. With python i could use ImageDraw, but i am out of the water with java.

is it possible to show this in a canvas on the screen and export this as svg or pdf? I dont know any libraries that could do this. So i would be happy to receive some suggestions/examples also along this way.

Comment: Is the text editable? Or is it viewable only?

Comment: text is viewable only, this is a display canvas

Comment: Are you using Swing? If yes check out the Text-API as suggested in an answer below. Higlighter is a option. For more flexibility subclass one of the View-classes. By this you can add special character decorations. The API can convert from model (character indexes) to view (graphic pixels) and vica versa, any font possible. Check out "Core Swing Advanced Programming" by K.Topley (ISBN 978-0130832924). With this book I enhanced JTextPane with hidden text, more style decorations and tracking of insertions and deletions (cmp. MS Word). For more information leave a comment.

Comment: hm can you make an example, that reproduces the grafic as described above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key is to deal with the [FontMetrics](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/FontMetrics.html) API. The best you can do is looking at this [reference doc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/text/measuringtext.html).

Here is a sample code demonstrating this usage. It draws red and blue lines around an "Hello world" text according a range of chars.

The text is inside a JLabel, but you can adapt the paint method on any component (but you will have to call `graphics.drawChars` to paint the text.)

(the code is not very nice, but it demonstrates the usage of FontMetrics)

```
package com.example.swing;

import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class DemoFontMetrics {

    public static void main(String[] args){
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        DecoratedLabel label = new DecoratedLabel("hello world !",new int[]{2,4}, new int[]{6,9});
        JPanel textContainer = new JPanel(new FlowLayout());
        textContainer.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(5,5,5,5));
        textContainer.add(label);
        frame.getContentPane().add(textContainer);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    private static class DecoratedLabel extends JLabel{

        int startBlue;
        int endBlue;
        int startRed;
        int endRed;

        private DecoratedLabel(String text, int[] blueRange, int[] redRange) {
            super(text);
            startBlue = blueRange[0];
            endBlue = blueRange[1];
            startRed = redRange[0];
            endRed = redRange[1];
        }

        @Override
        public void paint(Graphics g) {
            super.paint(g);   //draw text

            //set line with : 3
            Stroke stroke = new BasicStroke(3f);
            ((Graphics2D)g).setStroke(stroke);

            FontMetrics fm = g.getFontMetrics();
            int h = fm.getHeight();

            //compute blue line coordonate
            fm.stringWidth(getText().substring(0,startBlue));
            int x1 = fm.stringWidth(getText().substring(0, startBlue));
            int x2 = fm.stringWidth(getText().substring(0, endBlue));
            g.setColor(Color.BLUE);
            g.drawLine(x1,0,x2,0);// draw blue line

            //compute red line coordonates
            int x3 = fm.stringWidth(getText().substring(0,startRed));
            int x4 = fm.stringWidth(getText().substring(0, endRed));
            g.setColor(Color.RED);
            g.drawLine(x3,h-1,x4,h-1); // draw redline

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks for the suggestion. how could i integrate the linebreak and the grafics into this?

Answer (score 1):

If the text is displayed via `JTextPane` you can conveniently define a custom [`HighlightPainter`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/text/Highlighter.HighlightPainter.html), that draws lines above or under the text.

Then you can add highlights to the text pane programmatically by calling:

```
textPane.getHighlighter().addHighlight(startPos, endPos, 
        myLineHighlightPainter);
```

---

Images may as well easily be added to the pane, by:

```
textPane.setIcon(myImageIcon);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create svg directly for example: http://xmlgraphics.apache.org/batik/ it's an xml based vector graphics format.

EDIT: You can display svg in java, you can create pdf's with it from java. You can publish it in the web (simply as svg).